# Columns Multiplication in SQL

Tags: sql-server-2008

Consider two columns, `col_1` and `col_2`, the first from `table_1` and the second from `table_2` (data types of both columns are the same).

I need to multiply 1st row of `col_1` to 1st row of `col_2`, 2nd row of `col_1` to 2nd row of `col_2` and so on.

The result should be stored in `col_3` (of any of the tables given) by respective row.

For example :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/rd7zW.png

So please suggest me what query I need to write.

Comment: Are there any keys which define the relationship between table rows?  In other words, is there an ID column in table_1 which corresponds to table_2?

Comment: Ok do table 1 and table 2 relate to eachother on any fields even of those fields are not keys?  otherwise how do I know table 1 row one matches table 2 row 1 and not row 3 because table one had rows one and two deleted?

Comment: Do you have access to modify tables? Can you add identity column to both tables?

Comment: To rs,  yes i have access, let suppose there is an id columns in each table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO table_3 (col_1)
SELECT a.col_1 * b.col_1
FROM table_1 a
INNER JOIN table_2 b
ON a.id = b.id;
```

EDIT:

If it is in table_1, then you can just update col_3:

```
UPDATE table_1
  SET col_3 = a.col_1 * b.col_1
  FROM table_1 a
  INNER JOIN table_2 b
  ON a.id = b.id;
```

As far as order, that does not matter because it matches on the row id regardless.

Updated SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/605da/4

Comment: IF Col_3 is of Table_1 then ?

Comment: And also, Suppose if ID is not in ascending or descending order in table_2, but in table_1 it is in ascending order.

Comment: Glad to hear, and not a problem!

Answer (score 0):

You can put inline math in a SELECT statement to accomplish this. Assuming you have an ID column to match up the two source tables:

```
SELECT Table1.Col1, Table2.Col2, (Table1.Col1 * Table2.Col2) AS 'Col3'
FROM Table1
INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table1.ID = Table2.ID
```

Comment: But i need to fill col_3 also

Comment: Let Col_3 is in table_1, and it is blank.